# Use a date value in Excel to apply conditional formatting with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating an Excel sheet that will show when customers have paid and when they are late. With the help of a friend, I was able to come up with a formula that will tell us if a customer is past their due date by highlighting the cell red.

As far as I've seen, there's no way to get conditional formatting to change the blank cell to say "LATE", so I was suggested to try out VBA.

I have been able to change the colors and add the words I need, but how to get VBA to check the dates like the conditional formatting formula?

Here is the formula and what I have in my VBA sheet:

**Formula**

```
=AND(ISBLANK(B1),NOT(ISBLANK(B$1)),NOT(ISBLANK($A1)),DATE(YEAR($A1),MONTH($A1),DAY(B$2))<TODAY(),B$2<TODAY())
```

**VBA**

```
Const FORMATTED_RANGE As String = "$B:$ZY"

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Range(FORMATTED_RANGE)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Dim cellColor As Long
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Select Case Len(Target.Value)
  Case ISBLANK
      Target.Value = "LATE"
      Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
  Case Is <> 0
      Target.Value = "PAID"
      Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
  End Select
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I used some code I found online (thank you Rolf Jaeger from nullskull.com) for this so I'm not 100% if I need everything there, but it seems to be working fine, so I left it for now until I learn more about VBA.

Comment: Is your formula really working, because `=AND(ISBLANK(B1),NOT(ISBLANK(B$1)),...........` will always give you `FALSE` as `B1` cannot be blank and non-blank at the same time. Can you also provide sample data.

Comment: i won't recomend vba, u can try number formatting in your conditional format, like currency format we use the dollar sign ($), so instead of the dollar sign, put the 'LATE' word... ;)

Comment: i won't recomment VBA because using VBA to do such kind of formatting will make ur worksheet crawl speed

Comment: I agree with Mrig as for needed sample data to have us help you. @Mrig should that formula be pasted to other cells than it could still have (some?) sense

Comment: @user3598756 - Probably it make some sense for other cells but certainly not for Row1 and Row2.

Comment: Test your conditional formatting equation in an empty cell in the same row you want. Copy it down a few rows to make sure its working as intended.  When you have that step covered. copy the working formula back into your conditional formatting as required.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses and yeah the formula was working fine my only issue was getting the words to display after formatting. Marcos suggestion below works for me in this case to just have the word there but blended in then change the color with the conditional formatting so it pops up. 

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be possible to input text with conditional formatting, but you can change the font color. A solution could be to put the word "LATE in the specified cell(s) beforehand and set the font-color equal to the background-color, which makes the word invisable. When the condition (formula) evaluates true, the new format will change the font-color and the word LATE appears. No VBA requiered.

On the other hand: wouldn't a simple if-formula be better? Something like:

```
=if(amountpaid?,"PAID",if(late?, "LATE", ""))
```

If you wish you can then change the background with conditional formating

Comment: Hey Marco, I never thought of this! For this application it would work perfect!

Thanks a bunch for the help and yes that formula would be much better lol